# Unity3D - Post is empty when doing a UnityWebRequest

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a UnityWebrequest and it's working fine, but upon checking what's is the post in my PHP I found that the post is an empty array and the file is aswell. I found a StackOverflow post that has a similar problem. But it's solution did not work for me. So why is the post and file empty? I'm running this on a local server.

[UnityWebRequest POST to PHP not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627680/unitywebrequest-post-to-php-not-work)

**Web request**

```
static IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
{
    UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    request.chunkedTransfer = false;
    Debug.Log(bodyJsonString);
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    Debug.Log(request.uploadHandler.data.Length);
    request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);
    Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

**Php**

```
<?php
echo "POST: ";
print_r($_POST);
var_dump($_POST);

echo "Files: ";
print_r($_FILES);
var_dump($_FILES);
```

**Debugs**

> {"testJson":1}
>
> 8
>
> Status Code: 200
>
> POST: Array ( ) array(0) { } Files: Array ( ) array(0) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I added content via a WWWForm. Then the $_Post array was populated.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

after

```
UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
```

add

```
request.chunkedTransfer = false;
```

The thing that had me stumped for ages was I needed to have the filename in the url. I was using index.php so I was just using the directory path for the url. Soon as I used the **path including the filename** it started working fine.