# Get the link of the uploaded file with UnityWebRequest and php

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, post, unitywebrequest

I want to allow the user to use a local image from his machine and upload it to the server.

What I did is use UnityWebRequest in-game, load the image, send it to a PHP file on the server, and wait for the reply to remember the URL where the file si saved(to save it in Playfab later).

This is the code I made so far:

```
private readonly string setAvatarUrl = "http://myurl.com/setavatar.php";

private readonly string playerIdField = "playfabid";
private readonly string imageField = "img_avatar";

public IEnumerator SaveImageToDB(Texture2D image)
    {
        byte[] bytes = image.EncodeToPNG();

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField(playerIdField, player.playerId);
        form.AddBinaryData(imageField, bytes, "avatar.png", "image/png");

        UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest();
        www = UnityWebRequest.Post(setAvatarUrl, form);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string jsonFromDB = www.downloadHandler.text;    // Return empty string
            string imageUrl = JsonUtility.FromJson<string>(jsonFromDB);

            Debug.Log($"JSON returned: {jsonFromDB}");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
            {
                // Save the url
            }

            Debug.Log("Image upload complete!");
        }

    }
```

And this is the PHP file:

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$idplayfab = $_POST['playfabid'];

$path = 'avatar/'.$idplayfab;
if(file_exists($path)) {
    //dir exist
    $files = glob($path.'/*');
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file);
    }
} else {
    //not exist
    mkdir($path);
}

$uploadfile = $path ."/". basename($_FILES['img_avatar']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_avatar']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $array = array('result' => 'ok', 'url' => 'http://myurl.com/'.$uploadfile);
    $json = json_encode($array);
    return $json;
} else {
    $array = array('result' => 'ko');
    $json = json_encode($array); 
    return $json;
}
?>
```

The image is saved on the server but the problem is when I try to get the JSON to get the URL, the string is empty and I don't understand why.

I tried tons of solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity#answer-46008025) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486388/unity3d-post-is-empty-when-doing-a-unitywebrequest) but I cannot figure it out.

I also tried to use the deprecated WWW instead, but still, it doesn't work.

I'm kinda new to PHP so maybe it could be the PHP part the problem I believe.

Comment: Ive not seen return in php used that way. I would not expect your php code to return anything and the fact it is not suggests i am right.

Comment: Then can you please point me where can I find the solution, please? It's two whole days I'm trying to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an PHP expert but:

Afaik `return` is only used to evaluate certain functions e.g. for success or in order to further handle the result of something before responding to the client **on server side**.

What you want to do is rather sending your content as the http result to the client

=> You should rather use [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or [`print`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) which is used to generate the http output.